# Is there a way to append a header to a "grepped" output?

Tags: bash, grep

I have quite a large `csv` file (call it `file.csv`). It looks like this one:

```
col1,col2,col3,...
1,2,3
1,2,5
...
```

So after doing something like this `cat file.csv | grep "_some_pattern_"` I receive only the output values. Is there a way to append the header (the first line) to the output?

It would be very convenient...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `head` to print the first line and `tail` to search with `grep` starting after the header for the pattern.

```
head -n 1 file.csv && tail -n +2 file.csv | grep "some pattern"
```

Comment: If you want to dump the output into a single output file (e.g filter an CSV file)

`head -n 1 input.csv > output.csv && tail -n +2 input.csv |  egrep -i "some pattern" >>  output.csv`